How to access a private aks cluster from one azure account to another azure account and connectivity must be private? Not to use network peering
I Want to access a private aks cluster from one azure account to another azure account and connectivity must be private.
Note: Not to use network peering
How to do this? I'm pretty new to azure so little confused.

To access a private AKS cluster from one Azure account to another while avoiding network peering, you can use Azure VPN Gateway (P2S VPN).Follow the MS DOC:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-certificate-gateway for more details about VPN configuration.


Accessing a private aks cluster from one azure account to another azure account and connectivity must be private

Oneway is to create Azure VPN Gateway If you want to connect to private AKS cluster from one Azure account to another while avoiding network peering.
This works when youre using single to site configuration follow this Microsoftdoc

If you're using multiple vnets in mutiple regions you can use S2S Microsoftdoc
This will work even if youre using vnets from different location.
